# Can Google API domain-wide delegation service accounts enable gmail push through impersonating a user?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client, google-oauth

I created a service account on my Google Apps domain with domain-wide delegation enabled, and full gmail and pubsub API scopes enabled on the service account's client ID from my domain's control panel.

I can successfully instantiate a gmail API client and impersonate one of the domain's accounts with:

```
    credentials = oauth2client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(secret['client_email'], secret['private_key'], ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'], sub='accountToImpersonate@domain.com')

    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials.authorize(http)

    return discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

I am attempting to set a push notification webhook on the impersonated user's account with the following. The specified topic name is valid.

```
  request = {
    'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
    'topicName': 'projects/projectName/topics/topicName'
  }

  gmail.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()
```

I receive the following error after the call to watch:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch?alt=json returned "Invalid developer ID">
```

Calls to other gmail API methods (list messages, etc.) are successful.

Are service accounts with domain-wide delegation able to enable gmail push notification webhooks on a domain user's account?

Comment: I have tried it and yes it is possible. Did you grant access to gmail in your topic?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am encountering the exact same issue, and `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com` is indeed granted publish rights to my topic.

Comment: I'm not sure (yet), about to implement this myself. But it seems like if you first impersonate the user, and then try to subscribe to the topic with that user they would need access to that topic.

Possibly try instead of impersonating them, to just use the service account and give the actual userId instead of saying userId="me"... As in `gmail.users().watch(userId='xxxxxxxxx', body=request).execute()`

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully done this recently with a service account by doing just that ^^, simply pass the email address of the user instead of 'me' in the pubsub client setup call